# How to create an hexagon View in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to use a hexagon shape as a component for background icons.
I'm using copy/paste my codes from this url:
https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native

[image]

my code:

Hexagon.js

```
return (
  <View style={styles.hexagon}>
    <View style={styles.hexagonInner} />
    <View style={styles.hexagonBefore} />
    <View style={styles.hexagonAfter} />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  hexagon: {
    width: 100,
    height: 55
  },
  hexagonInner: {
    width: 100,
    height: 55,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  hexagonAfter: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -25,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopWidth: 25,
    borderTopColor: 'red'
  },
  hexagonBefore: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomWidth: 25,
    borderBottomColor: 'red'

  }
});
```

then:

```
  <View style={{width:100,height:100}}>
    <Hexagon />
 </View>
```

but It returns a red rectangle.

Comment: Can you try to add `justifyContent: "center"` in your style(`style={{width:100,height:100}}`)

Comment: which version of RN are you using? And which platform? because 0.57.x has  broken shapes like triangle etc on ios side: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21945

Answer (score 0):

Don't Make Other Component if you are facing the issue do it on same, this will return your desired hexagon!

Use Like this

```
            <View style={styles.hexagon}>
                <View style={styles.hexagonInner}>
                 <View style={styles.hexagonBefore}>
                 </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.hexagonAfter}></View>
              </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

This component is not 100% geometrically correct, but it's close enough for my use-case and closer (I think) than the other answers, where the triangles were a bit short:

```
//Distance from one straight line to the opposite one
const HEXAGON_SIZE = 200;

export const Hexagon = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.topTriangle} />
      <View style={styles.rectangle}/>
      <View style={styles.bottomTriangle} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rectangle: {
    width: HEXAGON_SIZE,
    height: Math.round(HEXAGON_SIZE * 0.57735),
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  topTriangle: {
    borderLeftWidth: HEXAGON_SIZE / 2,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: HEXAGON_SIZE / 2,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomWidth: Math.round(HEXAGON_SIZE * 0.57735) / 2,
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
  },
  bottomTriangle: {
    borderLeftWidth: HEXAGON_SIZE / 2,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: HEXAGON_SIZE / 2,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopWidth: Math.round(HEXAGON_SIZE * 0.57735) / 2,
    borderTopColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export default () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          rowGap: 60,
          columnGap: 15,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}
      >
        {Array.from({ length: 12 }, (item, idx) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.hexagon} key={idx}>
              <View style={styles.hexagonBefore} />
              <View style={styles.hexagonInner}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Text here</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.hexagonAfter} />
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  hexagon: {
    width: 100,
    height: 55,
  },
  hexagonBefore: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomWidth: 25,
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
  },
  hexagonInner: {
    width: 100,
    height: 55,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  hexagonAfter: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -25,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopWidth: 25,
    borderTopColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).